# What kind of input is used by NASA's TASAR?

Tags: commercial-aviation, weather, ads-b, navaids

I've found the Aviation SE to be a really interesting read so far, I'm excited to be here! I'm fairly new, but I'm also old!

What are the inputs for [TASAR](https://technology.nasa.gov/patent/LAR-TOPS-148) to crunch flight path optimization? Is it taking a look at the aircraft performance model, wind and weather, and ADS-B IN? Maybe TCAS-II traffic info? Would the weather data come from the onboard WXRadar or ground data?

I've read a few data-points that the long range weather info pilots tend to use is from received data (maybe ground radar or sat based weather data? both?), but the data is delayed to the point of being less useful, would the weather data need to take inputs from both Weather RADAR and NEXRAD type inputs?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange!

Answer (score 6):

The answer is "All of the above." The left hand side of this slide from a NASA Powerpoint deck pretty much covers your question.

[image: TASAR system generalized block diagram]

The full slide deck from the presentation can be seen [here](https://ral.ucar.edu/sites/default/files/public/events/2017/nbaa-fall-2017/docs/04-lewis-tasar-20171012-1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Juan! Slide deck is a term i usually hear from Consultants. You're not a consultant are you, Analyst Kyle?

Comment: Yes, I an a long time consultant and freelancer, and I use my real name here. I don't know who is Analyst Kyle.

Comment: Sorry, google it, it's a silly joke among MBA consultants

Comment: @Jeremy I did. Still no clue. No worries. :)